# The time tags in the dygraph are different from the one in the time series data. How do I solve this issue?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

[image: Code and Plot]

I have drawn a dygraph in R. But the time tags in the x axis are different from the actual time values in the data. The problem can be seen clearly in the attached image above- Code and Plot.

Comment: Hi Ankita, this could be because of some time-zone shifting.  Could you show what packages you are using?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I used lubridate and dygraph packages. The question has been answered by Carter below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `dygraphs` states that "By default dygraphs displays time-series using the time zone of the client workstation." Based off your plot I'm guessing your client (the local environment) is 6 hours or so from UTC, which is measured in London. Maybe when you plot the dygraph you could try this:

```
dygraph(series) %>% 
  dyOptions(useDataTimezone = TRUE)
```

Let me know if that works.